# Spring annotations: @Component works, @Repository doesn't

Tags: java, spring, repository, components

I have got little problem with my spring app. here is my code:

(repository)

```
import com.maciej.entities.Etwas;
import com.maciej.repository.EtwasRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.List;

HERE IS THE PROBLEM -----  @Component works, while @Repository doesn't
public class EtwasHibernateRepository implements EtwasRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Etwas> findAll() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Etwas create(Etwas etwas) {
        entityManager.persist(etwas);
        return etwas;
    }

    @Override
    public Etwas read(int id) {
        TypedQuery<Etwas> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Etwas e WHERE e.id=:id", Etwas.class);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        Etwas etwas = query.getSingleResult();
        return etwas;
    }

    @Override
    public Etwas update(Etwas etwas) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(int id) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

here is my simple service class:

```
import com.maciej.entities.Etwas;
import com.maciej.repository.impl.EtwasHibernateRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class EtwasService {
    @Autowired
    private EtwasHibernateRepository etwasHibernateRepository;

    public boolean save(Etwas etwas){
        etwasHibernateRepository.create(etwas);
        return true;
    }

    public Etwas read(int id){
        return etwasHibernateRepository.read(id);
    }
}
```

and simple testing class:

```
import com.maciej.Config;
import com.maciej.entities.Etwas;
import com.maciej.services.EtwasService;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext acac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        Etwas etwas = acac.getBean("etwas", Etwas.class);
        etwas.setSth("STATATASTAT");

        EtwasService etwasService = acac.getBean("etwasService", EtwasService.class);
        for(int i=0; i<=20; i++){
            etwasService.save(etwas);
        }

        System.out.println(etwasService.read(7).toString());

        System.out.println(etwas.getSth());
    }
}
```

The problem is, that when i annotate `EtwasHibernateRepository` with `@Component`, everything works fine. When I add, actually apoperly - `@Repository` annotation I get a stacktrace:
do you have anny suggestions what do I do wrong?

ps
the code is really simple, embroiled and made just for tests so dont care about that :)

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'etwasService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.maciej.repository.impl.EtwasHibernateRepository
>   com.maciej.services.EtwasService.etwasHibernateRepository; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.maciej.repository.impl.EtwasHibernateRepository] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
>     at com.maciej.test.Test.main(Test.java:12)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire field: private
>   com.maciej.repository.impl.EtwasHibernateRepository
>   com.maciej.services.EtwasService.etwasHibernateRepository; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.maciej.repository.impl.EtwasHibernateRepository] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
>     ... 17 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.maciej.repository.impl.EtwasHibernateRepository] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
>     ... 19 more

**Update:** Configuration

```
import com.maciej.entities.Etwas;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public Etwas etwas(){
        return new Etwas();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
        emf.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.maciej.entities"});

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        emf.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return emf;
    }

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource dataSource(){
        BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();
        bds.setUsername("root");
        bds.setPassword("maciek");
        bds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
        bds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        return bds;
    }


    private Properties additionalProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf); //entityManagerFactory().getObject()
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you don't program to interfaces.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class EtwasService {

    @Autowired
    private EtwasHibernateRepository etwasHibernateRepository;
```

The autowired dependency is of the fully implementing class, whereas it should be `EtwasRepository`. This will make it work for both `@Component` and `@Repository`. Next to that it is also the proper way to do it.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class EtwasService {

    @Autowired
    private EtwasRepository etwasHibernateRepository;
```

Beans annotated with `@Repository` will have automatic exception translation enabled and this is applied with AOP. By default Spring uses JDK Dynamic proxies which are interface based. It will create a dynamic class implementing the `EtwasRepository` interface and apply the aop interceptors. This makes a bean of the type `EtwasRepository` and not of the `EtwasHibernateRepository` type anymore.

This conversion isn't applied when annotating your bean `@Component`.

A note about your configuration the explicit declaration of the `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` isn't needed. That is already taken care of.

Comment: so now I would like to ask few questions: 1.What about @Service? I have service class now without interfaces implemented and @Service works for it. 2. I am quite new in spring and jpa and actually dont know: what does exception translation do? 3.should I create interfaces for both: services and repositories and "code with interfaces"?

Comment: `@Service` doesn't have, at the moment, additional behavior applied. Your `@Transactional` does but due to the fact that you don't implement an interface a cglib proxy (class based) will be created. In general I favor interfaces over classes but as with many things ask 10 developers and get 12 answers :).

Comment: yup, but I wonder about one thing in interface-programming: lets look at Spring MVC, there are @ Controllers @ Services and @ Repositories. @ Controller should call @ Service and @ Service should call @ Repository then. So: if I create separated interfaces for repository class and service class, each time that I want to add new method to repo interface I also have to add it to service interface as well. Is there any option or design pattern to avoid adding methods twice each time?

Comment: If you have a one-on-one mapping either your service layer is wrong (to fine grained) or yourdata access layer is wrong (to coarse grained). Your service layer should be providing use-cases/services not a simply save/load/update method. In general when there is a one-to-one mapping there is business logic in the web layer which should be in the service layer.

Comment: Architecture is a different question and shouldn't be answered here in comments. So accept/up-vote this answer (as it answers the `@Component` and  `@Repository` question you had. On the pros and cons of interface based programming already exists questions here on stackoverflow.

Comment: ok thanks for your answers, really helpful. for now I cant vote up the answer because my reputation is only 11. I will mark it as accepted if I find the button :))